# how to print all values of the field "cell -> pos" of this struct in c:

Tags: c, struct

**how to print all values of cell->pos** 
why it gives an error and how to solve this error
"error: expected expression before 'cell'"

```
typedef struct cell
{
     int pos[6][9]; 
    struct cell* next;  
}cell;
```

I tried to do like this

```
typedef struct cell
{
    int pos[6][9];
    struct cell* next;
}cell;

void print_cell()
{
    int col,row;
    for (row = 0; row < 6; row++) {

        for (col = 0; col < 9; col++)
        {
          printf("%d " , cell->pos[row][col]);
        }


    printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    print_cell();
    return 0;
}
```

*it gives an error
error: expected expression before 'cell'*

Comment: In your code there is no *variable* named `cell`. There is only a *type* of that name. It's not clear what you are really intending to do as there is also no code that initialises the values in the structure.

Answer (score 1):

- You just declared type `cell`, but created no variable having that data type. Create one.
- `->` is for dealing with pointers. use `.` to access member of struct directly.
- You should include `stdio.h` or declare `printf()` to use the function.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* include proper header */
typedef struct cell
{
    int pos[6][9];
    struct cell* next;
}cell;

cell cell_value; /* create a variable */

void print_cell()
{
    int col,row;
    for (row = 0; row < 6; row++) {

        for (col = 0; col < 9; col++)
        {
          printf("%d " , cell_value.pos[row][col]); /* use the variable */
        }


        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void){
    print_cell();
    return 0;
}
```

This code may be more useful because arbitrary instance of `cell` can be printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct cell
{
    int pos[6][9];
    struct cell* next;
}cell;

void print_cell(const cell* c)
{
    int col,row;
    for (row = 0; row < 6; row++) {

        for (col = 0; col < 9; col++)
        {
          printf("%d " , c->pos[row][col]);
        }


        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void){
    cell c = {{{0}}, NULL};
    print_cell(&c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might be better in matter of coding style to avoid "magic constants" like `6` and `9` directly in the `print_cell`'s body. Both can be replaced by `sizeof c->pos / sizeof c->pos[0]` and `sizeof c->pos[0] / sizeof c->pos[0][0]` respectively or even clearer by the symbolic constants like `#define POS_WIDTH 6` and `#define POS_HEIGHT 9`.

Comment: Never declare functions of the standard library yourself. Always use the standard headers! This not only becasue one can introduces typos or errors while the headers are better tested, but worse, because an implementation may add attributes, etc which are not meant to be used by the end-customer. They also might use macro-wrappers for the functions. Please especially don't recommend this to beginners!